# Android stop execution of a http request

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask, abstract

I would like to know if it is possible to stop execution of Code in a responseReceived of a http request example :

```
new HttpRequest() {
        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(JSONObject result) {
        // doing a lot of thing
        }
}.get("http://niceUrl");
```

Inside the onResponseReceived I'm doing a lot of thing ( parse Json, add data to list, etc..)

When I'm calling this function :

```
private void stopExecutionOfOnResponseReceived(){
    // I would like to stop the previous HttpRequest and launch a new One
}
```

The HttpRequest is an abstract class who extends extends AsyncTask String, Void, JSONObject

Comment: asynctask class has method `cancel()` check that

Comment: If you can call cancel method, you can't stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use to abort method.
This example demonstrates how to abort an HTTP method before its normal completion.

```
public class ClientAbortMethod {

    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://httpbin.org/get");

            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getURI());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                // Do not feel like reading the response body
                // Call abort on the request object
                httpget.abort();
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is usefull cause I'm using HttpUrlConnection for request